# How to install StrongLoop Loopback in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

What is the difference between 
apt-get install -g strongloop and 
apt-get install -g strong-cli ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `apt-get` was a typo and you actually meant `npm`, the difference is [strong-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strong-cli) is the old package name and it was renamed to [strongloop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strongloop).

You should use `npm install -g strongloop` because the old package is no longer updated.